# is the suggested PDA correct?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

so i have this language

$$ L = \{x^{i}  v^{j}  z^{j+2}  w^{k}  v^{i+k} | i,j,k \ge 0 \}$$

i made this PDA for it .

states $  =  \{q_0 ... q_5 , final\}   $

alphabet $= \{ x,v,z,w \}$

stack alphabet  $= \{ A , B , \bot \}$

$\bot$ is the end of the stack symbol

transition function and start state and final state in the graph

[image]

i have two questions :

1. is the PDA correct?
   the idea is simple :

in q0 push A for each x seen

in q1 push B for each v seen

in q2 pop B for each z seen

q3 is for the +2 of z

in q4 push A for each w seen

in q5 pop A for each v

if you get to the end of the stack symbol go to the final state

my main concern is : did i get the epsilon transitions right

2. is it possible to give a DPDA for it ?
   (it seems that if we had $i,j,k \ge 1$ then omitting red epsilon transitions
   from the above PDA gives us a DPDA . cannot we just some how get along  with the condition $\ge0$)